# How to do serial communication handshaking via RTS and CTS using RXTX in java

Tags: java, rxtx

```
// my configuration using RXTX library in java
SerialPortObj.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);// Hardware flow control settings
            SerialPortObj.setRTS(true);   
            SerialPortObj.notifyOnCTS(true);
```

I am assuming that the serial interface standard itself maintains the hardware flow control using **RTS/CTS** handshaking every time before sending and receiving data.

My problem statement is that i want before sending actual data every time, an **RTS** signal must be send to the receiver and receiver confirms back with the **CTS** signal.

Answer (score 2):

There is 3 modes of flow control:

- Hardware Flow Control - this is the manage the handshake with 2 pins (RTS/CTS) of the conector (rs-232). This one it's the best choice;
- Software Flow Control - this is the manage the handshake with 2 character (XON/XOFF) you send when you want to initialize a transmission or when you want to end it;
- None Flow Control - this mode it's easy way, but you can lost data. There isn't control to flow of data.
  For more information visit website below:
  http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-11.html#ss11.7

if you want to use the RTS/CTS method to manage your flow control on rs-232, you must configure the serial port for this mode:
`serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
 SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);
 serialPort.setDTR(true);`

after you need configure the notifications:
`serialPort.addEventListener(this);
 serialPort.notifyOnCTS(true);
 serialPort.notifyOnDSR(true);
 serialPort.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);`

After that the hardware flow control will work like charm.

For the full code visit here:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andrelup/GSM-gateway/master/GSMConnect

Comment: I use RXTX from https://github.com/NeuronRobotics/nrjavaserial and the change of CTS is signalled when I run my app with java but not with javaw. The OS is Windows 10, haven't tested with other OS yet.
What could be the reason? ... and how can I solve this issue?